# If MVC controller can also return JSON result, why use ASP.NET Web API for the same purpose?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Why would one use ASP.NET Web API Controller when we can return JSON using MVC controller?

Comment: Different pipes, same result - minor changes. you can use a web api controller in a MVC project, it's just easier for apis IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data formats, content negotiation, self-hosting(avoiding IIS) and importance of method signature are the key reasons to use web api. Please have a look at the following links and it will help you in understanding the difference between the both:-

http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/7bfdd512-91e3-49a4-865d-6dd03ace73fb.aspx

[Using WebAPI or MVC to return JSON in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10346342/using-webapi-or-mvc-to-return-json-in-asp-net)