# Why we didn't keep using ASP.Net MVC for RestFull Services instead of ASP.Net Web API?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I know that Asp.Net Web API was the junction between WCF Web API and ASP.Net MVC because there were 2 ways to build RestFull services.

But if ASP.Net MVC already does everything what Web API does (accepts all HTTP verbs and can return JSON), why use the Web API at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But, if you wanna create a REST Api Library only?

- A lot of application are using it day by day. And that why microsoft decides create this.

I aggree that sometimes it's a little bit confused and seems like you can do everything with MVC only. But, there are soft differences between both technologies.

You could see also in this thread:

[Difference between MVC 5 Project and Web Api Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22589245/difference-between-mvc-5-project-and-web-api-project)