# Migrating from asp.net webforms, do you recommend mvc or web api?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, webforms

I know I´m late for this party.
Currently migrating form asp.net webforms to newer coding technologies and paradigms. Barely got started with asp.net mvc and now I´m noticing all this fuzz about mvc vs webapi. I'm an oldschool programmer and don´t really feel confortable with the "use both" approach, if there´s no need to. Please consider this:

- My web projects focus on dynamic dashboards/admin sites to manage CRUD operations for tons of SQL records, generate reports on demand, statistics, etc.
- No static websites at all (like info sites, portfolios and such).
- Performance over UI design. Actually bootstrap basic UI is enough for me.
- Pure ADO over entity framework, whenever possible.

Any tip or guidence on what I should choose would be very much appreciated.

*** Edit/Closing ***

Hi again and thank you for your feedback.
After a lot of reading and experimentation I´ve decided to give a real hard tryout to asp.net webapi + angular.js, mostly because I want to leave the door open for multiplatform/device usage (not web only).

Also, I found a very interesting article/tutorial in https://superdevelopment.com/2013/12/16/building-rich-web-apps-jquery-vs-angular-js/

It may be a little old but I think it´s worth reading, specially this extract right here: "Angular.js and WebAPI is a new way to build rich interactive web applications that fully embraces what can be done with a Web browser, JavaScript and C# rather than relying on out-dated paradigms that complicate the process for all but simple use cases. If your users and clients are expecting an application in a web browser that behaves like a native app on their desktop or smart phone, then jQuery + ASP.NET MVC is not the most straightforward way to build it."

Anyway, thanks to all and I hope this info helps others in the programming community.

Comment: purpose of MVC and WebAPI is different MVC is more UI driven and WebAPI is restfull service / data driven ... check this link to start of ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22589245/difference-between-mvc-5-project-and-web-api-project

Comment: also, if you have any needs to communicate with SOAP/XML I would recommend WCF, which would be able to transfer REST as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your application is going to be consumed various type of devices then prefer **web api**.

if your application is like website or portal where user has very little interaction then go for **MVC**