# Difference in webapi in asp.net and asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

In Visual Studio I have a choice of creating an ASP.NET Core (2) and ASP.NET application. I understand the differences between the core and non-core frameworks, but it seems there is a difference in how ASP.Net MVC/webapi is handled by the two versions, specifically and focusing only on webapi I'm getting the impression:

**Core can create 2 types**
1. Webapi: a RESTful service, and nothing more
2. Web MVC: MVC web application using razor with webapi available

**However, non-core (for want of a better word)**
1. webapi: RESTful service but built on (you have to have) MVC
2. mvc: A MVC without ability to use webapi. MVC can use razor or web forms

Can someone let me know why ASP.Net MVC has been separated like this as it's really confusing, and whether future versions (I'm presuming .net core seems the more up to date) will converge in how they work (i.e. full-fat MVC will allow separation of web api).

thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22589245/difference-between-mvc-5-project-and-web-api-project