# Asp.net web api services

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

What is the big difference between normal asp.net mvc and asp.net web api ? When i know i can use a normal action result to return a Json data and call it with javascript or an ajax onsuccess function or even with jquery GetJson() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asp.Net MVC is used to create web applications that returns both views and data but Asp.Net Web API is used to create full blown HTTP services with easy and simple way that returns only data not view.

[ASP.NET Web API vs. ASP.NET MVC “APIs”](http://encosia.com/asp-net-web-api-vs-asp-net-mvc-apis/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is similar post [ASP.NET WebApi vs MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350853/asp-net-webapi-vs-mvc).

The answer is not accepted one, but the other one.

Or check [this](http://encosia.com/asp-net-web-api-vs-asp-net-mvc-apis/) or [this](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/webapi/Y95G050413-Difference-between-ASP.NET-MVC-and-ASP.NET-Web-API.html).