# MVC vs Web API for Multi Page App. Is The Future Web API?

Tags: design-patterns, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm starting a new project in super early story phase and I'm a little unsure of what design pattern to use. The app is a reporting app that will allow users to design reports and download them. The app will basically be a wizard style multi page data selector.I'd like to offer the functionality to build these reports from a desktop app too.

Considering the advances in Web API over the past few years, would it be crazy to not use it over MVC?

I've been out of the development game for a bit and it seems that Web API and an angular or other js front-end is the route of choice for new application developers looking to focus on server side business logic along with as many consuming front-ends as possible. There's very little data persistence in this app apart from settings etc.

So am I right to go the web API route? Would this be a good example of when NOT to use MVC? Or I there a middle ground that uses both that's universally understood as being a smart design choice?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET WebApi vs MVC ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350853/asp-net-webapi-vs-mvc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, both the MVC and Web API approach allow separation of your model and logic from presentation, which fits your requirement to have the wizard working via a desktop app as well as web.  For me it comes down to your requirement for development time vs. application performance.

Using MVC will be quicker however you'll incur a server round trip unless you use some kind of proprietary controls in your view that are AJAX based. With Web API only, you're going to need to do a lot of manual JSON manipulation and be reliant more on your front-end MVVM (a client-side representation of the MVC pattern), which is *always* more time consuming.

Using Web API definitely keeps you more loosely coupled, has the potential for overall highest performance, and if you have a need to publish your API out to the public, you've got that in place. It will come at development time cost though.

So, if you just want to get something up and running quickly, use MVC is my advice. Need a very loosely coupled, optimally performant solution? Go the Web API route. Microsoft are now almost merging Web API and MVC anyway so Web API is essentially the controller of an MVC pattern.

Also I should add in relation to Vlince's answer that a single page web application is simply an application that makes use of multiple DOM elements at the client-side that are shown or hidden according to the input. Kendo UI is a framework particularly suited to that approach, however it can be done with nothing more than pure JavaScript, and isn't a Microsoft specific technology.

Answer (score 3):

This is a difficult question to answer because it raises more questions.

In short, the answer is: It depends.

As you’re well aware, `MVC` is a **Pattern** that is used to separate application’s concerns. **Design Patterns** on the other hand, are solutions to software design problems.

Microsoft’s branding of `asp.net MVC` was initially introduced to offer an *alternative* to `webforms`. Both of these patterns (`webforms and MVC`) are viable solution for when you want to create a website or web application. It all comes down to what needs to be done and how efficient your team is in either one of them.

Microsoft `asp.net Web API` is a framework for building web `APIs` on top of the .NET framework. Back in the days, we would create `Web Services` using `.asmx` files. Then, they introduced `WCF` and now, we have `Web API`.

`Web Services` and `WCF` still exist today and are valid choices but...the newer stuff does overcome some of the limitations found in the earlier stuff. There are `Pros and Cons` in using anyone of them. You need to pinpoint what does one offer over the other and if it fits your need.

> The app is a reporting app that will allow users to design reports and
>   download them. The app will basically be a wizard style multi page
>   data selector.I'd like to offer the functionality to build these
>   reports from a desktop app too.

What’s not clear is when you say the ability to ***design*** reports. Do you mean that your users will get to choose where and how they want things to look and feel on the report? For example, user1 wants its logo at the top right while user2 wants it at the bottom left etc...How much will your users be able to **“design”** their reports?

Then you mention something about a wizard. Are the steps in your wizard there to help the user **design** his report or are the steps there to **act as parameters** to your report?

You then mention that you’d like to offer this wizard-like functionality from within a `Desktop` application as well...my first instinct would be to `host` your web application somewhere and from within your `Desktop` application, have a `browser control` that points to the `URL` of your wizard-like web application.

> Considering the advances in Web API over the past few years, would it
>   be crazy to not use it over MVC?

Well...they serve different purpose.

In the past years, you ***typically*** created a website using `webforms` and/or `asp.net MVC` in order to design web pages/Views which were then sent to the user’s browser.

`Web APIs` are ***typically*** used for creating APIs that does not return Views or Web Pages but instead, returns `data`.

Notice how I use ***typically***...that’s because the **trend** for the past 2-3 years now has been to create `Web APIs` and use a client side framework such as `Angular` to invoke that `Web API` and render `Views`. With this approach, you pretty much by pass the need of using `asp.net MVC` and/or `webforms`.

Keep in mind that although I say **trend**, I do not mean this will die in the next few months or years. There is value in creating these types of application which is beyond the scope of this post. But remember that client side framework requires people knowing them...so you’ll need to take that into consideration if you choose to go down that route.

By the way, Microsoft did introduce yet another alternative to asp.net MVC called `SPA` (`Single Page Application`) which allows you to build web application using the above mentioned approach.

With all that, I’m not even sure if I did end up answering your question :-)

I guess I’d still need more clarification on the exact task at hand.