# Does Kendo UI Grid expose a method to check if the model state is valid?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm currently displaying a Kendo UI Grid in a modal.  I've got a few custom validations hooked up which are working fine.  When the modal's "Save" button is clicked, I need to be able to check whether the grid is currently in a valid or invalid state.

Since I'm only using custom validation, it's certainly possible for me to keep a running track of the errors and then check the error count upon the modal closing, but I was hoping the Kendo UI Grid kept up with this and exposed something easy like myGrid.isValid() or some such thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you use web-api on server side call `ModelState.IsValid`

[More about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17790107/how-to-return-modelstate-errors-to-kendo-grid-in-mvc-web-api-post-method)

What you mean about `custom validation`?

If you using `kendo custom validation` like in this reference [reference](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing-custom-validation) that way user cant enter wrong values in editor. But if you want IsValid option, that way you need to impliment `kendo.validator`. Define validation rools in your model and then call `validate()`:

```
// attach a validator to the container and get a reference
var validatable = $("#myform").kendoValidator().data("kendoValidator");

$("#save").click(function() {
  //validate the input elements and check if there are any errors
  if (validatable.validate() === false) {
    // get the errors and write them out to the "errors" html container
    var errors = validatable.errors();
    $(errors).each(function() {
      $("#errors").html(this);
    });
  }
});
```

[Validator in kendo docs](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/validator)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a way to validate that the kendo grid is valid prior to submitting the data.

Comment: Edit my answer. Is that helpfull now?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to accomplish what you want

```
let validatable;

$(document).ready(() => {
    validatable = $("#gridId").kendoValidator().data("kendoValidator");
})

function PostData() {
    if (validatable.validate()) {
        // save the grid data
    }
}
```