# Where is MVC in Web API?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to get a hold on `WebAPI` so please excuse if the question is too naive to ask.

Been hearing that `WebAPI` is using `MVC` and is integrated in to it.

Just created a sample `WebAPI` project but under `References` I find not `System.Web.Mvc` dll.

Why? Or am I missing anything important?

[image]

***EDIT:***

About `System.Web.Mvc`, [the MSDN says the following paragraph](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc%28v=vs.118%29.aspx):

> The System.Web.Mvc namespace contains classes and interfaces that support the ASP.NET Model View Controller (MVC) framework for creating Web applications. This namespace includes classes that represent controllers, controller factories, action results, views, partial view, model binders, and much more.

Comment: What steps you followed in creating WebAPI project, It should be New Project -> ASP.NET MVC4 Web Application -> Web API -> OK

Comment: @Habib: Just created a empty `ASP.NET Empty Web API 2` project. But still, `System.Web.Mvc` should be there right

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed. No - MVC is separate from Web API.

Comment: @Zabavsky: `System.Web.HTTP` contains info about `APIControllers`. You are right. Thanks :)

Comment: @DavidHoerster: So, `WebAPI` does not follow `MVC Framework` ? I am pretty confused because everywhere in Internet, `they talk or mix both MVC and WebAPI` ?

Comment: New Project > Web > ASP.NET Web Application > Web API > OK. This should work, the `Add folders and core references for: MVC and Web API` should be automatically ticked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And it should not be there. ASP.NET Web API is very similar to MVC, buit is not integrated with it or whatever. Web API can live completely outside of MVC framework perfectly fine. Which is good - while building HTTP service you wouldn't want to include any HTML rendering features whatsoever into your project.

Think of it that way - `System.Web.Mvc` contains end-user-facing features that MVC uses, like views, view results. WebAPI is not a end-user-facing thing, it does not generate HTML or run javascript. Purpose of Web API is to provide means for creation of HTTP services - very different from MVC framework.

MVC and Web API share several similar approaches. Take controllers for example. Looks like they behave similar in both frameworks. However you may discover that implementations are different. MVC uses `System.Web.Mvc.Controller`, while Web API uses `System.Web.Http.ApiController`. More detailed explanation on the reason why is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9494966/difference-between-apicontroller-and-controller-in-asp-net-mvc). On the other hand - routing. Both frameworks use the same implementation of routing which resides in `System.Web.Routing`.

Frameworks are similar, but can exist completely separately. That is why there is no reference between them.

Answer (score 0):

For Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web do the following:

`New Project > Web > ASP.NET Web Application > Web API > OK`

This should work, the `Add folders and core references for: MVC and Web API` should be automatically ticked by VS.

100% working - I've just created a project and all the references are there.