# AspNet core web Api usage of ApiControllerAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

When I create a new controller in the API project, it generates a controller class with `[ApiController]` attribute, like this:

```
[ApiController]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
 //implementation
}
```

I've seen a few webapi projects where usage of this attribute is omitted.
Microsoft documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.apicontrollerattribute?view=aspnetcore-2.1) says:

> Indicates that a type and all derived types are used to serve HTTP API
>   responses. The presence of this attribute can be used to target
>   conventions, filters and other behaviors based on the purpose of the
>   controller.

But still, I don't get the idea.
Can someone explain what is the purpose of this attribute with the real-life example?

Comment: Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16305878/9456781) for a real-life example and the accepted answer for further insight.

Comment: Always check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/index?view=aspnetcore-2.1#annotation-with-apicontroller-attribute), its all pretty well documented. It just adds additional conventions for WebApi controllers, which makes sure you have to use less attributes to describe it (FromBody attribute becomes optional, model validation happens automatically etc)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This is well-explained in the docs: [Annotation with ApiController attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#apicontroller-attribute-3), which explains that adding the `[ApiController]` attribute to a controller does the following:

1. [Automatic HTTP 400 responses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#automatic-http-400-responses)

   Adds an action filter that returns a 400 response if `ModelState.IsValid` is `false`.
2. [Binding source parameter inference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#binding-source-parameter-inference)

   Changes model-binding conventions. For example, `[FromBody]` is inferred for complex-type parameters.
3. [Multipart/form-data request inference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#multipartform-data-request-inference)

   Infers a Content-Type of `multipart/form-data` for parameters marked with `[FromForm]`.
4. [Attribute routing requirement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#attribute-routing-requirement)

   Mandates that all actions must be attribute-routed.

You can see how this is actually done in the [source](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/release/2.1/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Internal/ApiBehaviorApplicationModelProvider.cs#L81):

```
foreach (var actionModel in controllerModel.Actions)
{
    if (!isApiController && !actionModel.Attributes.OfType<IApiBehaviorMetadata>().Any())
    {
        continue;
    }

    EnsureActionIsAttributeRouted(controllerHasSelectorModel, actionModel);
    AddInvalidModelStateFilter(actionModel);
    InferParameterBindingSources(actionModel);
    InferParameterModelPrefixes(actionModel);
    AddMultipartFormDataConsumesAttribute(actionModel);
}
```

If you're not interested in any of the features described above, you can omit the attribute. It's also possible to suppress individual features by configuring the [`ApiBehaviorOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.apibehavioroptions?view=aspnetcore-2.1) class.