# AJAX Post returning NULL in Controller (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, model-view-controller

I've got a Javascript function, and I want it to pass through data to my controller.

This is my Javascript code:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Home/CreateUser",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify({name: 'Dylan', email: 'an@email.com', password: 'password'}),
        success: function (response) {
            window.location.href = 'dashboard';
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert('Error while signing up: ' + error);
        }
        })
```

..and this is how I've got my Controller set up to receive the request:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateUser(string name, string email, string password)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Data received successfully: Name - " + name + ", Email - " + email + ", Password - " + password);
        return Content("Data received successfully: Name - " + name + ", Email - " + email + ", Password - " + password);
    }
```

Currently each value is passed through as *null* and I can't figure out why this isn't working. The request in the browser network tab appears to be sending the Json so I think there is something wrong with how I have set up my controller. I've tried setting up a class and receiving that, but that still won't work.

Thanks,
Dylan

Comment: "I've tried setting up a class and receiving that" by that you mean you made a C# class with "name", "email", and "password" properties, then changed the CreateUser method to have only a parameter of that class type (with some arbitrary parameter name)? If you try it again, try adding `[FromBody]` before the parameter's type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use one of the following options:

#1 - specify `[FromBody]`

```
public ActionResult CreateUser([FromBody]string name, [FromBody]string email, [FromBody]string password)
```

#2 - use [`[ApiController]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53579723/aspnet-core-web-api-usage-of-apicontrollerattribute) attribute on your controller

#3 - create a model for your payload

```
public class RequestModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

then use it

```
public ActionResult CreateUser([FromBody]RequestModel request)
{
   Console.WriteLine($"Data received successfully: Name - {request.Name}, Email - {request.Email}, Password - {request.Password});
   ..
}
```

More info about Model Binding could be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-8.0&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-2.1)