# How to display all row data rather than just diplaying first row using SQL Query in MVC

Tags: c#, linq, t-sql, model-view-controller

I'm using the code below, but when I call the query, it can only display data of the first row

```
String query = @"select s.item Type
                 from TypeTable t1
                 outer dbo.Split(t1.Type, ',') s"

dt = SQLCon.getDatatableFromSQL(query);
var _Type = (from rw in dt.AsEnumerable()
             select new TypeAction
                        {
                            Type = rw["Type"].ToString(),
                            // ActiveStatus = Convert.ToBoolean(rw["ActiveStatus"].ToString())
                        }).FirstOrDefault();
return _Type ;
```

Current:

```
Type A
```

Expected:

```
TypeA
TypeB
TypeC
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `FirstOrDefault()` to `ToList()`.

```
FirstOrDefault()
```

Returns the first element of a sequence, or a default value if the sequence contains no elements. Rather than using `.ToString()` you should use `Convert.ToString(<object>)` as it will handle null reference exception also. [This SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55430726/how-to-load-data-into-datatable-using-ajax-in-mvc) can help you much better if you want to display the result in a table.

Comment: how can i call this method in the ActionResult of the controller? after change to ToList

Comment: @Fate Please check this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/55431549/10532500